# Assistance with using AND + OR operators Together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to reduce the amount of conditional formatting rules required to change a row colour.

Each row has a drop drop to select if the xray scanner being used is s1,s2,s3,s4 or s5. Once selected, its moved to a different sheet. 'FINISH' is entered to show the process has been completed.

Instead of having a different formula for checking each page and turning the row green, i want one big formula to check the pages together.

The current code i've been using is;

AND($F2="S1",'X Ray 1'!$F2="FINISH") - Checks if s1 is selected and finished has been entered.

AND($F2="S2",'X Ray 2'!$F2="FINISH") - Checks if s2 is selected and finished has been entered.

AND($F2="S3",'X Ray 3'!$F2="FINISH") - Checks if s3 is selected and finished has been entered.

AND($F2="S4",'X Ray 4'!$F2="FINISH") - Checks if s4 is selected and finished has been entered.

AND($F2="S5",'X Ray 5'!$F2="FINISH") - Checks if s5 is selected and finished has been entered.

Therefore, i'm trying to connect all the above statements into one long formula.

My horrible attempt is below.

=OR(AND($F2="S1",'X Ray 1'!$F2="FINISH")),(AND($F2="S2",'X Ray 2'!$F2="FINISH")),(AND($F2="S3",'X Ray 3'!$F2="FINISH")),(AND($F2="S4",'X Ray 4'!$F2="FINISH")),(AND($F2="S5",'X Ray 5'!$F2="FINISH")))

Comment: You don't need outer parentheses around the AND - and you have an extra parenthesis after the first AND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You BigBen,

Answer is

```
=OR(AND($F2="S1",'X Ray 1'!$F2="FINISH"),AND($F2="S2",'X Ray 2'!$F2="FINISH"),AND($F2="S3",'X Ray 3'!$F2="FINISH"),AND($F2="S4",'X Ray 4'!$F2="FINISH"),AND($F2="S5",'X Ray 5'!$F2="FINISH"))
```